# Ms Word Add-in debugging can't open document

Tags: ms-word, add-in

I am trying to create Ms word 2013 add-in but I am stuck at the very begining. I have clean word instalation without any addins enabled and it runs fine. Then I have created add-in project in Visual studio 2013 and when I run the debug mode Word starts but when I try to open any document It freezes eventhough I haven't modifiead anything in the add-in project.

EDIT: I am using Application level add-in and I have simply debugged the template generated by Visual studio

```
namespace WordAddIn1
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    #region VSTO generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Since the add-in should do nothing, I have expected it to do so and the Word to run as without any addin. When I debug it it hits the breakpoint when I set it to the Startup method and the initial Word page appears, but then it doesn't respond when I click on the blank document. The same thing happens when I don't clean the addin and run Word with the addin enabled without debugging.

Also when I do the same thing except for the ms Excel, it works just fine.

Comment: What type of add-in is it: an Application-Level Add-In, Document-Level Customization, or Office Automation ([explanatory link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/12/02/understanding-the-three-approaches-to-office-development-using-vsto.aspx))? What form does it take: ribbon tab, task pane, something else? What function(s) does it perform? What troubleshooting have you done ([troubleshooting techniques link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haahmadi/archive/2010/05/26/my-vsto-add-in-does-not-load.aspx))? Exploring these topics, if they do not resolve the issue, may suggest code to share.

Comment: Strange. When I try to recreate your issue and set the break point at `InternalStartup`, Word pauses at the splash screen and does not go directly to displaying a document. Are you testing with an instance of Word already open when you debug (as this might cause the freezing when clicking on an open blank document)? Is your add-in listed under File|Options|Add-Ins as an active or inactive application add-in? I should note that I tested with VS 2013 and a Word 2010 add-in project so there may be some difference when creating a Word 2013 add-in.

Comment: No, Word is closed before I start debugging and when I check the add-Ins options afterwards, my add-in is displayed as active one. Maybe it is caused by Word, I will try it with some other version and then I will write again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to solve this problem. It is strange but the only thing that worked for me was to install Word 2010 along with the word 2013 and then run the add-in in the Word 2010. Then I have tried to debug the add-in in Word 2013 once again and it worked!